# A very very weird problem html object tag

Tags: html, object, tags

When I insert a music file into the object tag, nothing appears. The browser is the latest update, and my object tag only has problem with music files!!!!???

please answer.....

```html
<object data="demo.mp3">
     <param name="autoplay" value="true">
</object>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add path to existent file

```
<object data="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   <p>alternate text</p>
</object>
```

Comment: Why is this music file now showing up but not my file !!
So I wrote a really weird problem?

Comment: And also on the website W3SCHOOLS.COM where the example did I did not see any outbound issues from my browser?

Comment: @KMahdj paste here the w3schools example. And probably you dont path correctly the file. Try <object data="/demo.mp3">

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use <audio> tag?
like this:

```
<audio controls autoplay>
    <source src="demo.mp3"></source>
</audio>
```

Comment: I'm investigating the object tag